# I get a crash using Palette.From(bitmap).Generate(), how do I use correctly?

Tags: android, eclipse, palette

I am trying to generate colors to a palette on **Android (Eclipse IDE)**. After running there is a freeze-crash on handset. Apparently i am not using the API correctly, but on search there is very little information on how to use palette.From(bitmap).Generate(); I have this code

```
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette.PaletteAsyncListener;
import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette.Builder;
....

int vibrant, vibrantLight, vibrantDark, muted, mutedLight, mutedDark;
public Palette palette;

void decodeColors2(){
    ....
    myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, rWidth, rHeight, false); 

    palette = Palette.from(myBitmap).generate();


    vibrant = palette.getVibrantColor(0x000000);
    vibrantLight = palette.getLightVibrantColor(0x000000);
    vibrantDark = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(0x000000);
    muted = palette.getMutedColor(0x000000);
    mutedLight = palette.getLightMutedColor(0x000000);
    mutedDark = palette.getDarkMutedColor(0x000000);
```

}

Please can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong and how to correct my code to get a full run rather than a crash.

Also how do I use Palette.Builder(bitmap, number)?
EDIT: crash log:

```
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.graphics.Palette
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at com.example.liveideas.Liveideas.decodeColors2(Liveideas.java:699)
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at com.example.liveideas.Liveideas$3.onPictureTaken(Liveideas.java:264)
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:823)
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
11-07 19:00:33.135: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 19:02:04.585: W/Sensors(31684): sensorservice died [0x4d9e3660]
11-07 19:02:04.605: I/Process(31684): Sending signal. PID: 31684 SIG: 9
11-07 19:02:04.605: E/AndroidRuntime(31684): Error reporting crash
11-07 19:02:04.605: E/AndroidRuntime(31684): android.os.DeadObjectException
11-07 19:02:04.605: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
11-07 19:02:04.605: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:3305)
11-07 19:02:04.605: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:121)
11-07 19:02:04.605: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
11-07 19:02:04.605: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
11-07 19:02:04.605: E/AndroidRuntime(31684):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks

Comment: Where you put this code? In onCreate()? And please add the crash log

Comment: I placed it in a function void decodeColors2(){...}

Comment: I have edited the code to indicate this

Comment: And the crash log?And when you call the function?

Comment: If device is crash, it's mean there is crash logs

Comment: I have retrieved the crash log from logcat and edited to OP

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't defined the support library properly.  according to the docs:

> To add a Support Library without resources to your application
>   project:
>
> Using Eclipse
>
> Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the
>   SDK Manager. Create a libs/ directory in the root of your application
>   project. Copy the JAR file from your Android SDK installation
>   directory (e.g.,
>   /extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar) into your
>   application's project libs/ directory. Right click the JAR file and
>   select Build Path > Add to Build Path.

In your case you need android-support-v7

Comment: thanks. I downloaded Android support library and can find android-support-v4.jar but not android-support-v7.

Comment: I also had this crash =====  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.graphics.ColorUtils  ===== but cant find ColorUtils.jar.   How do i fix?   Many thanks

Comment: Had this latest crash after adding android-support-v4.jar to build path

Comment: According to your log you need V7 version. Anyway, move to studio, much more easy to work

Comment: I think it might be easier if i could know how to get android -support-v7, if you know please share. Don't penalise me for not migrating :) many thanks

Comment: People's have different experiences on things. For me getting my project  to work on AS was hell! My second attempt was a huge struggle for several weeks, i finally gave up when my Android Studio forum questions don't get answered anymore. So for me thats a very bad experience and talking of AS is like going backwards. :)

Comment: I just didn't used Eclipse for more than a year but I'm sure it's shouldn't be hard to download this jar

Comment: This path: `<sdk>/extras/android/support/` didn't include V7 direcory?